# How to uncheck checkboxes using a DOM selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, selector

I have created a dom selector that essentially has all of the checkboxes as a node array in part of my app:

```
 var checkboxes = document.getElementById("factors").querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

This returns a node array for 10 checkboxes with each of the node items looking like this:

```
>checkbox[0]
><input name="chkVal0" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_0" checked="checked" style="user-select: none;">
```

I want to have a function that unchecks all of the checkboxes at once, but I can't seem to achieve this using the dom selector. I've tried a few things on a single item first, but it doesn't seem to uncheck the box:

```
var checkbox_one = checkboxes[0];

//Using jquery and props
$(checkbox_one).prop("checked", "unchecked") //Nothing

//2nd try
$(checkbox_one).prop("checked", false) //Nothing

//3rd try using attr
$(checkbox_one).attr("checked", "uncheck"); //Nothing

$(checkbox_one).attr("checked", false); //Nothing
```

I've tried a few similar things using `aria-checked = false` and `value=off` but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue and get the boxes to uncheck using the dom selector?

Comment: `$(checkbox_one).prop("checked", false)` works; `.attr("checked", false)` sets the _initial_ checked value, which won’t help you; the string from the other attempts is meaningless. Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: `$(checkbox_one).prop("checked", false)` should uncheck the checkbox. You could also make it easier on yourself and just do `checkbox_one.checked = false;`.

Comment: I've  basically been testing this out in the Browsers Dev console. The js code is in a completely separate js file from the html and I'm using other dom selectors without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the `NodeList` and set the `checked` property to `false` on each checkbox.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("factors").querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for(const checkbox of checkboxes){
   checkbox.checked = false;
}
```

With jQuery, you need to pass the entire `NodeList` to the jQuery function, or directly pass a selector to it.

```
$(checkboxes).prop('checked', false);
// or
$('#factors input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: True; yet the above solutions are still not working for me. I did find multiple answers but none seem to be working for me.

Comment: @gwydion93 Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @gwydion93 Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Vanilla js we need to loop over each checkbox to change its value .. but with jQuery it's a piece of cake

See this example =>

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

**Js**

```
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
   // Using forEach loop 
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = false)
```

**jQuery CDN**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
  // a single line of code with jQuery !
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
```